# SQL-style explode on Dask Series or DataFrame column

Tags: python, dataframe, explode, series, dask

I have a Dask Series that contains a column with a list of values. I want to perform a SQL-style explode to create a new row for each index value and corresponding list element. For this particular problem, the lists are all of the same length.

Example of a single row:

**index**          **column**
123            [value1, value2, value3]

Desired transformation:

**index**          **column**
123              value1
123              value2
123              value3

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a pandas dataframe, this can look like

```
df.column.apply(pd.Series, 1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

To do this to a Dask dataframe, you'll want to use [map_partitions](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions), to do exactly the same thing to each partition of the data:

```
def func(df):
    return df.column.apply(pd.Series, 1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df.map_partitions(func)
```

Comment: For a series, you do not need the `.column`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome! if you want to give the 'exploded' column a desired name add .to_frame('desired_exploded_col_name') after reset_index(..)